# Input Property Binding in Angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-template

Below is the code of a component which has a `@Input()` property.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
selector: 'cd',
template: ` 
<h2>{{input1}}</h2>

`
})

export class cdComponent{

 @Input() input1: string;

}
```

And I would like to use this component in other component, and the code of parent component is mentioned below.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
selector:'main',
template: `
<cd [input1]="test"></cd>
<h2> Main Route </h2>
`
})

export class MainComponent{

}
```

When `MainComponent` gets displayed in the browser, I was expecting "test" text from child component to be also displayed.

But the "test" text is not getting displayed. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not displayed because you are passing variable named `test` to `input1`, but it doesn't exist. When you use `[]` to pass value to input, it looks for variable named `test`, my guess is that you want to pass just string `test`. There are two ways to do this:

```
<cd [input1]="'test'"></cd>
```

Or:

```
<cd input1="test"></cd>
```